# Trouble writing a MySQL procedure with CASE/WHEN

Tags: mysql, procedure

I'm trying to write a procedure which will either return a subset of all rows or just return all rows depending on input. 
I have some code I'm playing with right now (pasted below). In this code, I'm manually setting `var1` and `var2` (these will eventually be passed parameters) and querying given their values.

Right now the code returns rows that satisfy the constraints `userDataTypeName="currentGPA"` and `userDataText="4,"` but if either of these values are NULL the code returns no rows.  I would like all rows in the table to be returned if the value for `userDataText=NULL` instead of none.  I think maybe COALESCE can help me accomplish this but I'm not sure.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE var1 varchar(20);
        DECLARE var2 varchar(20);
        SET var1 = "currentGPA";
        SET var2 = "4";
    SELECT udata.user_id FROM userdata udata
        WHERE(
    COALESCE(udata.userDataTypeName, '')  =
    CASE
            WHEN var1 IS NULL THEN ''
            ELSE var1
    END
        and
        COALESCE(udata.userDataText, '') = COALESCE(var2, '')) LIMIT 30;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That CASE seems equal to COALESCE(var1,'').

Now the query, you are applying COALESCE to every row in the table.  This is pretty inefficient, it would be better to compare the values in each row to the desired values.  In this case, the desired values are NULL or var1/var2.  This gives the following query which may do as you wish far more efficiently (query based on OP + following comments)

```
SELECT udata.user_id 
FROM userdata udata
WHERE udata.userDataTypeName = COALESCE(var1,'')
AND (
    var2 IS NULL
    OR
    udata.userDataText = var2
)
LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I considered all the cases for values of var1 and var2 passed in...here's what happens:

var1 and var2 both have proper values: returns results.

var1 has proper value, var2 is null: returns nothing.

var1 is null, var2 has proper value: returns nothing.

var1 is null, var2 is null: returns nothing.

I'm looking for this but if var1 has a proper value and var2 is null I want all the results in the table to be returned.

Comment: Your description is very confusing, it feels like you have taken a scenic route to a simple problem.  What you are saying is that if var1 is specified, use it to restrict the results.  If var2 is specified, use it to restrict the results.  If var2 is NULL (not specified) then return all results, i.e. ignore the var1 limitation?  This makes little sense.  Are you able to post up your actual stored procedure perhaps?  Maybe some sample data along with expected output?  A table schema too could be useful.  If you can dump the table into sqlfiddle.com then that would be best.

Comment: I assure you I'm not trying to take a scenic route - if I knew a simpler way to do it I would have!  Anyway, your solution got me thinking and I ended up with something like this, which does what I want:

BEGIN
 DECLARE var1 varchar(20);
        DECLARE var2 varchar(20);
        SET var1 = COALESCE("currentGPA",'');
 SET var2 = COALESCE("4",'');
        SELECT udata.user_id 
FROM userdata udata
WHERE (
    udata.userDataTypeName = var1
) AND (
    (
        var2 = ''
    )
    OR
    udata.userDataText = var2
)
LIMIT 30;
END

Comment: I updated the query based on later feedback, so that if var2 is null (empty string) then it effectively ignores it.  In your last comment it indicates that var1 is a straight-forward match, which was not apparent from your original post

Comment: Yes - I actually was basing my initial code on code that someone else wrote using all the COALESCE()s (they used more than what I simplified down to in my OP).  The reality of it is that my table will never have NULL values in userDataTypeName or userDataText so it is pretty much useless trying to use that as a condition anyway.  Thanks for your help and I'm sorry the OP was confusing.  I wrote it in desperation at 4am :)

Answer (score 0):

**CASE** What?

```
CASE var1
   WHEN IS NULL THEN ''
   ELSE var1
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - my way of using case is just another supported syntax.